# Where are inbuilt icons in flutter located (default location in flutter folder)

Tags: flutter, icons

I want to use flutter inbuilt icons as assets. So I want default location where all of flutter icons are located in flutter folder of flutter installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think they are. If you look at the IconData class (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IconData-class.html). You will see that the description says 'A description of an icon fulfilled by a font glyph.'

Taking an example of one of the Icon values:

```dart
static const IconData list_alt = IconData(0xe81b, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');
```

I believe what that is telling us is that the Icon is being defined by the position 0xe81b in the Unicode font family called MaterialIcons

Comment: I'm not sure it's a unicode font... just a font that Google is providing for consistency in Material, and subject to change at their whim.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to imply that there's a fontFamily named 'MaterialIcons'.  Not sure you can get it easily from any part of the Flutter distro, but https://material.io/resources/icons/ will show how to download or reference the font for your material designs.

```
static const IconData ac_unit_outlined = IconData(0xe005, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')
```

Comment: I believe the location of the MaterialIcon ttf is here:
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/font

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the original question, but likely tangentially helpful...

To visually identify & search/filter icons, both from the included MaterialIcons from Google and those created by the Community, check out:
https://materialdesignicons.com/

And to use them, the related pub.dev package for [material_design_icons_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/material_design_icons_flutter).

Comment: Why is that pub.dev package even needed?  You get all of that built in to flutter!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz How do you get auto-complete access to the community created icon names without using that package?

Comment: It says that's a "Material" package.  Are you truing to replace Google's Material Icons (free to use, and updated from time to time) with something else?  The Material Icons auto-complete just fine.

Comment: That package contains 2-3X more icons than that available from the default set of Material Design icons available with flutter.  How are you proposing to get access to those icons without using that package?

Comment: Well, it's not really "material design" any more.  That's for Google to produce, and the rest of us to consume.  You just have a bunch more icons, maybe call them (as you have) "Community Icons".